# Using Tradingview/Pinescript, how do you capture the values for price and volume of the first bar on the chart

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

In pinescript (version 5), you can capture past values of price and volume, e.g. for the values from 100 bars back:

```
    P100b = close[100]
    V100b = volume[100]
```

In principal, to get the values from the very first bar on any chart you would replace 100 with the total number of bars on the chart. The number of bars on any chart is equal to bar_index + 1 (https://kodify.net/tradingview/bar-data/bar-number/). Despite that, the following code compiles but won't chart and produces the error "the study references too many candles in history".

```
BI = bar_index + 1 
P0 = close[BI] 
plot(P0,title="P0",color=color.yellow,linewidth=1, style = plot.style_line)
```

However, the following works as expected, ie it dynamically plots the total number of bars on the chart. This indicates that the variable BI did capture the correct value and can go back that far in history:

```
BI = bar_index + 1
plot(BI,title="bar_index + 1",color=color.fuchsia,linewidth=1, style = plot.style_line)
```

Any ideas how to capture the values for price and volume for the first bar of any chart?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with var variables ([description in pine reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_var)). Such variables are initialized at the first call and are not changed on each bar like ordinary variables. They can only be changed by reassigning a new value. Here is an example for your case:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
var firstClose = close
plot(firstClose)
```